# Action attribute that restrict action method by url pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there an action attribute that allows restricting action method by url pattern?

In my controller, I would like to to have two SearchOrder actions.  One for editing order and one for viewing order.  If the url path is /Order/EditOrder/SearchOrder/1, I would want it to execute this action.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("SearchOrder")]
    public ActionResult EditOrderSearchOrder()
    {
         . . . .
    }
```

But if the url path is /Order/ViewOrder/SearchOrder/1, I would want it to execute this action.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("SearchOrder")]
    public ActionResult ViewOrderSearchOrder()
    {
         . . . .
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a situation where [areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx) could be used; an area called _Order_, containing two controllers _Edit_ and _View_, each containing a _Search_ action method (the repetitive use of "Order" seems unnecessary). This may be less [surprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) for the next developer who works on this codebase...

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways. Some of them are
Write in RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Properties",
    url: "Order/EditOrder/SearchOrder/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "YourControllerName",
        action = "SearchOrder",\\ bcoz you have given action name attribute otherwise your method name
        id = UrlParameter.Optional \\ you can Change optional to Fixed to make passing Id parameter compulsory 
    }
);
```

If using Mvc5, you can do Attribute Routing by following a simple  syntax:

```
[Route("Order/EditOrder/SearchOrder/{id?}")] // ? For optional parameter 
public ActionResult EditOrderSearchOrder(){}
```

And 
To enable attribute routing, call MapMvcAttributeRoutes in RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute(“{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}”);

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

Comment: The MVC5 attribute routing solution would be the most desirable solution for me.  Unfortunately, I'm using MVC4.